# How can I use ReportUnit with NUnit3?

Tags: nunit, reportunit

I have checked ReportUnit and it only supports NUnit 2 results. I couldn't use NUnit 3 results with ReportUnit.

1. Are there any other tools that support an NUnit 3 xml file?
2. Or does ReportUnit have NUnit 3 support?

Answer (score 2):

Reportunit 1.5 supports NUnit3

Answer (score 0):

NUnit3 has the option to print results in the same format as NUnit2 - this may be the easiest workaround until "ReportUnit" supports NUnit3 natively.

Use the command line option:

`--result=yourfilename.xml;format=nunit2`